# Mousebinding in a WPF TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, mouse, key-bindings

Is there a way to do a Mouse- or KeyBinding in a WPF treeview?

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Main.TreeItems}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>                           
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">                          
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}">
                <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding TreeViewClickCommand}" MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"/>
                </TextBlock.InputBindings>
             </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

This doesn't work. If i use my Command on a button not in the treeview then the command is fired. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this Command works outside the TreeView, I assume your TreeViewClickCommand is located in the DataContext of your Window/UserControl.

Use AncestorType to refer to the TreeViews DataContext (which is the same as the Windows DC, if you did not set it manuelly):

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=DataContext.TreeViewClickCommand}"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [AttachedCommandBehavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) to do this.

Comment: Care to comment why this is not applicable?